# Pyudev's ObserverMonitor locks up GIL when monkey patched

Tags: monkeypatching, eventlet, flask-socketio, pyudev

Whenever I use eventlet's monkey patching (necessary for Flask-SocketIO) the disk_monitor_thread() prevents other threads from firing. Eventlet and monkey patching is a must for me. Is there a way to get pyudev's MonitorObserver to place nice and release the GIL with monkey patching?

```
from threading import Thread
from pyudev import Context, Monitor, MonitorObserver

import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

def useless_thread():
    while True:
        print 'sleep thread 1'
        time.sleep(2)

# Monitor UDEV for drive insertion / removal
def disk_monitor_thread():
    context = Context()
    monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)
    monitor.filter_by('block')
    def print_device_event(action, device):
        if 'ID_FS_TYPE' in device and device.get('ID_FS_UUID') == '123-UUIDEXAMPLE':
            print('{0}, {1}'.format(device.action, device.get('ID_FS_UUID')))
    print 'Starting Disk Monitor...'
    observer = MonitorObserver(monitor, print_device_event, name='monitor-observer')
    print 'Disk Monitor Started'
    observer.start()

t1 = Thread(name='uselessthread', target=useless_thread)
t1.start()
disk_monitor_thread()
```

results in:

```
sleep thread 1
Starting Disk Monitor...
```

and never moves forward from there

Comment: Flask-SocketIO does not require monkey patching when using eventlet. It is typically the application that does. Have you tried running without monkey patching, assuming your application is fine with it?

Comment: And also, as [recommended in the eventlet docs](http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html#monkeypatching-the-standard-library) see if moving the monkey patching statements above the other imports help.